# What are the mesh and raster layers in QGIS that are included when a GRIB2 file is imported?

Tags: qgis, raster, band, precipitation, grib-2

I am currently working with grib2 files from the [RDPA dataset](https://dd.weather.gc.ca/analysis/precip/rdpa/grib2/polar_stereographic/24/?C=M;O=D) in QGIS.

When one of these grib2 files is imported, there is a raster layer and a mesh layer that is generated. I am struggling to understand how QGIS is creating the mesh layer from the bands in the grib2 file. (The image below shows the two layers created when the grb is imported).

[image: The Raster and Vector Layers included from the Grib2 file]

My goal is to use the total prepitation data that is put into the mesh layer, but I need it in a raster.

When I try using the raster calculator, I am not sure which bands to select from the grib file in order to generate the correct raster (somehow the generated mesh has the correct precipitation values, but its a mesh file, not the required raster). In the below image, I would like to use the band data (red) to create a raster that contains the data from the mesh file (blue).

[image: Raster calculator options]

Any advice on how I can get the precipitation data that is already in the mesh component of the imported grib into a new raster layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the same data in two diffèrent format, mesh and raster.

the Raster Band 1 contain "Total precipitation [kg/(m^2)]" and Raster Band 2 contain "(prodType 0, cat 1, subcat193) [-]" from the mesh